# Runtime alert in azure function

Tags: azure-functions

I want to set up an alert if the function is executed for more than 10 seconds.
I use Application Insights.
What condition will allow me to get this exception when creating an alert?
http://joxi.ru/5mdkzzEIkyvDg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's workerd: in resourse group I selected Application Insights, but not my function app, and then in condition I can select "duration my function"